# Value stored in database becomes spaceless?

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

While inserting data into a database via a HTML form, the value of the input field gets stored without spaces?

```
<input type="radio" name="pack" value="package name">
```

The value which gets stored in the database is `packagename` ? **WITHOUT SPACES**

I also tried to insert the value using a PHP variable :

```
<?php $phpvariable = 'SOME TEXT HERE'; ?>
<input type="radio" name="package" value="<?php echo $phpvariable; ?>">
```

but still the value gets stored without spaces? How to fix this ?

**Code behind the PHP script**:

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$username = $input->get('username');
$Package = $input->get('pack');
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$columns = array('Username', 'Package');
$values = array($db->quote($username), $db->quote($Package));
$query->insert($db->quoteName('y5bu2_selected_packages'))
      ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
      ->values(implode(',', $values));
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

P.S - Its a Joomla website!

Comment: show the complete code ..

Comment: How are you storing it in the database?  How are you confirming that it loses the space character?  At what point does it lose the space character?  (That is, are you sure it's in the database or could it be in whatever code displays it later?)

Comment: Without spaces within the text? Or with trailing spaces stripped?

Comment: try sending a key then replace that key with the text you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's because radio type input does not accept values with spaces, you can try to set the same text but replacing spaces with a special char like `_`(underscore) then, in your submit php script, you take this string and the replace using `str_replace()` undersocres with white spaces, before you do your query.

```
<?php 
$phpvariable = 'SOME TEXT HERE';
$phpvariable = str_replace(" ","_",$phpvariable);
?>

<?php 
$phpvariable = $_POST['data'];
$phpvariable = str_replace("_"," ",$phpvariable);
?>
```

Comment: i updated my question..i hope you can modify your answer a bit in my code's context!